# Swap existing responsive site with Cordova

Tags: cordova

Does some one has experience with adding push or other native functionality to an already existing responsive website? The idea is to leave the website as it is and just wrap it with cordova so we can use the native features. But i am not sure if the application will be approved by apple because it's just a 'wrapper' for a online website. Hope you can help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is one of the use cases that Cordova was created for. Your existing mobile website code can be used as the starting point for a "native" mobile application, and depending on your situation, you can create separate website and application deployments from a single codebase. However, whether Apple will approve the application for distribution in the App Store depends entirely on the implementation, not Cordova.

Answer (score 0):

The App Store [Review Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/) definitely seem pretty strict. I think this is the one you are concerned about:

- Apps that are not very useful, unique, are simply web sites bundled
  as Apps, or do not provide any lasting entertainment value may be
  rejected

I would say that if you add some native functionality like push notifications it will help your case but it's just guessing. I suggest you read through the guidelines very carefully and compare them to your website.

The process you have to go through before getting your app to the App Store may be not that trivial, especially if you have to start from scratch. But it's a good value.